# Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute un API a partir de un evento en base de datos

Tags: java, sql-server, api, eventos, jpa

Les explico un poco, tengo una situación donde recibo registros en una base de datos, por otra parte tengo que consumir un api para reportar esos registros que se crearon.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma usando Java de enterarme que se registró algo en la tabla para venir a tomar los datos y consumir el API que notifica.

La idea sería algo automático y en línea como algún evento, nada de hacer tareas automáticas que se estén ejecutando solas cada cierto tiempo.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias ver como implementar una websocket https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).